# Bind Value with asp:Label without knowing the Column Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

I am currently binding the data with an asp:NET label as following:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="hhmIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

However, I would like a solution which does not require me to bind the data by column name since the solution we are after will utilise several different tables (all with the same structure, but different column names).

This is my backend in C#:

```
SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("select CRY_HHM_ID, CRY_HRY_KEY from [WH_EXT].[dbo]." + tablesDropDownList.SelectedItem.ToString()+" where "+colName+"= '"+selectedChildKey+"'", myConnection);
myReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(myReader);

this.selectedLeafGridView.Visible = true;
selectedLeafGridView.DataSource = dt;
selectedLeafGridView.DataBind();
```

A solution similar to this one [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/166531/Optimal-Alternative-To-DataBinder-Eval?msg=4175050#xx4175050xx) might make sense, however, I could not understand how it works:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <%# ((DbDataRecord)Container.DataItem).GetString(0)%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I would be happy with either getting this to work, or propose possible alternatives, depending which is the best.

Comment: Even if the column names in the tables are different, you can alias them to the same common name: `Select col1 as [CommonColumnName] from table`

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but you can not bind a label to something random in the DB. You need to specify the column. Like "Name" label should be bound to "Name" column in DB. Unless you are binding a manually generated DataTable to a Data control.

Comment: Are the amount of columns constant when querying from multiple tables?

Comment: @SpaceApple - Yes, most of my tables have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix your Data Layer code with your GUI code.

You should bind to a (collection of a) Generic Object (one that you make) ........and SEPARATELY......... populate (a collection) of those objects with different Business Logice / Data Layer calls.

```
[Serializable]
public class ValueHolder
{
    public string Value01 { get; set; }                         
    public string Value02 { get; set; }     
}

public class ValueHolderCollection : List<ValueHolder>
{}
```